# Communicating with the Erlang shell run with run_erl from shell scripts

Tags: erlang, sh, io-redirection, run-erl

I have an Erlang application which is run via [`run_erl`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/run_erl.html). It creates files `erlang.pipe.1.w` and `erlang.pipe.1.r` and I can start a console via `to_erl`. So far, so good. Then I needed to talk to it from a shell script. The obvious thing to do was

```
#!/bin/sh

EXPR=$1
PIPE_DIR=/tmp/mware
PIPE=$PIPE_DIR/erlang.pipe.1.w

echo $EXPR >> $PIPE
```

Initially it worked, but now I am getting an error:

```
-sh: can't create erlang.pipe.1.w: Interrupted system call
```

`ls` shows that the file already exists. What's going wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a pipe (`|`) rather than append (`>>`). E.g.

`echo 'io:format("hello ~p", ["world"])' | to_erl $PIPE_DIR`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not really familiar with the method you're currently using but I earlier gave some example of [three methods of connecting two nodes from the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525506/run-erlang-from-unix-shell-with-complex-params/4525599#4525599). Maybe some help on the way. Cheers!