# Automate Erlang shell nodes with unix batch

Tags: bash, erlang, erlang-shell

I can run many erlang nodes from batch file. But, can i pass some arguments to erl that cause it to execute some commands?

Comment: looks like erl -eval solved my problem.

Comment: Maybe my response [on a similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525506/run-erlang-from-unix-shell-with-complex-params/4525599#4525599) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wish to start a node, and for example start an erlang application, or run a few lines for the start up of the node you can run the erl command the following way

```
erl -eval "application:start(my_app)"
```

or starting the node with several commands

```
erl -eval "Res = my_first_module:my_start_fun(MyArg),
           my_log:log(Res),
           another_module:another_fun(Res)"
```

the same has above but putting the node into a background process

```
erl -sname nodename 
    -setcookie nodecookie 
    -eval "Res = my_first_module:my_start_fun(MyArg),
           my_log:log(Res), 
           another_module:another_fun(Res)" 
    -detached
```

But if you want to run erlang in a more "scriptwise" way I do suggest you look into [escript](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html) and the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525506/run-erlang-from-unix-shell-with-complex-params/4525599#4525599)  like [D.Nibon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/531395/d-nibon) suggested

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can.
If you ask more specific, i will get you a more specific answer, if i'm able to.
This seems like a more "erlang"  question than a "bash" question.

Comment: start terminal -> start erl -> run some command in erlang shell (module_name:function_name()). First two steps i already can do, but stuck with third.

Comment: Is there a way to give the erl command a string, which will interpreted as erlang command?